# Laravel - Standard way to handle a blade for multiple purposes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am building a send/receive message system. The messages may be `created`, `replied` and `forwarded`. The same blade file is used for all of them. For creation, every field `title, body, recipient, attachment` is empty but for reply, the `recipient` is the sender of the message. In `forward` recipient field is empty. Different situations for fields may happen based on the action.

This is my question, Should I create different blade files for every action or based on the action, I should put `if else` statement in the blade file and create the corresponding field?

Both approaches have its own drawbacks. for different blade files, It is difficult to maintain the web site. for example changing a color or something in UI, requires changing in every blade file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the diifrent controller for functionality wise

Comment: @Muthusamy all actions are in MessageController. I created different routes for `reply(), forward()` and `create()`

Comment: so you can create a diffrenet blade for all routes

Comment: @Muthusamy Indeed I can do that. But I am looking for the standard way

Comment: @Muthusamy Both approaches have its own drawbacks. for different blade files, It is difficult to maintain the web site. for example changing a color or something in UI, requires changing in every blade file.

Comment: better u can write te UI in seperate page and include in the blade file, so when u need to change the design you can work only in one page, it will affect all the pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186217/discussion-between-muthusamy-and-no-one).